# AddFontResource not working on my Win64 Delphi Application

Tags: delphi, winapi, vcl

My application is a VCL Win64 application built with Delphi 10.3.3.

For some reason, `AddFontResource()` is not working properly on Windows 11.

Here is what I have so far:

```pascal
procedure TfrmMenuPrincipal.CriaFontesArialNarrow;
const
  cFonteArialNarrow: array [0..3] of string = (
         'ARIALN', 
         'ARIALNB', 
         'ARIALNBI', 
         'ARIALNI'
  );

var
  _FontFolder,
  _Resorce,
  _FontFile: string;
  _Res: TResourceStream;
begin
  _FontFolder := TSpecialFolders.GetAppDataFontFileFolder; // 'C:\Users\Leonardo\AppData\Roaming\MyApp\Fonts'

  for _Resorce in cFonteArialNarrow do
  begin
    _FontFile := _FontFolder + _Resorce + '.TTF';
    if not FileExists(_FontFile) then
    begin
      _Res := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, _Resorce, 'FILE');
      try
        _Res.SaveToFile(_FontFile );
      finally
        _Res.Free;
      end;
    end;
    AddFontResource(PChar(_FontFile));
    //Screen.Fonts.Add(_FontFile );
    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);
  end;
//  Screen.Fonts.Add('Arial Narrow');
end;
```

No errors, app runs fine, but it can't use the fonts inside the application.

I read somewhere that font files should be on a folder that is contained in the `PATH` environment variable, but I have tested that and it didn't work.

Also, I have checked several Google hits, and other threads here at StackOverflow, but no luck.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried installing your font files in `C:\Windows\Fonts` instead? That said, rather than saving your fonts from your app's resources to disk, why not simply use `AddFontMemResourceEx()` instead to install the resource data as-is? Are you trying to allow other apps to use your fonts, or just your own app?

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with Remy, to build the fonts into the application as a resource and using AddFontMemResourceEx() to load the font. For example...

```
{$R IonIconsFont.res}
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.Title := APP_NAME;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.ShowMainForm := True;

  {Load embedded fonts *before* creating form so that positioning based on font is correct...}
  LoadResourceFont('IonIconsFont');
  
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Here is my LoadResourceFont function:

```
function LoadResourceFont(const ResourceName: string): Boolean;
var
  ResStream: TResourceStream;
  FontsCount: Integer;
  hFont: THandle;
begin
  ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, ResourceName, RT_RCDATA);
  hFont := AddFontMemResourceEx(ResStream.Memory, ResStream.Size, nil, @FontsCount);
  Result := (hFont <> 0);
  ResStream.Free;
end;
```